# Is this a jquery.live() side effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery. When I was using .live('click', handler) instead of .click(handler), I found the event handler can be triggered even though the object is disabled! Is this a bug of .live() all it is an anticipated behavior? And if do not want the side effect, what should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative/workaround, use this instead:

```
$('#myForm').delegate('#myButton', 'click', handler);
```

Here's a fiddle showing that this *does* produce the desired results:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/YcS8A/

Answer (score 2):

Looks [like a bug](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/live-inconsistency-with-disabled-buttons).

Comment: And this happens on IE8. chorme does not have this problem